# Dos formularios con mismo ID Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo dos formularios y mientras uno se muestra el otro está oculto, pero ambos tienen el mismo ID y me crea problemas al recibirlo en mi ajax, pienso que creando dos IDs diferentes pero no sé como recibirlo en el Ajax.

El ID es `city_id`

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control box" id="status" name="status" onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
                <option value="select" selected>Seleccione el tipo de cuenta a crear</option> 
                <option value="local">Cuenta Local</option>
                <option value="user">Cuenta de empresa</option>
            </select>
        </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-12" id="local" style="display: none;">
       {!! Form::open(['route' => 'accounts.store']) !!}
                            
       <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
               <select name="province_id" id="province_id" class="form-control">
                   <option value="">Elija una provincia</option>
                   @foreach($provinces as $province)
                   <option value="{{ $province->id }}">{{ $province->province }}</option>
                   @endforeach
               </select>
          </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
             <select name="city_id" id="city_id" class="form-control">
                 <option value="0" required>Ciudad</option>
                 <option value=""></option>
             </select>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group text-left">
           {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block']) }}
       </div>

      {!! Form::close() !!}

     </div>

     <div class="col-12" id="user" style="display: none;">

         {!! Form::open(['route' => 'accounts.store']) !!}
                            
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
                <select name="province_id" id="province_id" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Elija una provincia</option>
                        @foreach($provinces as $province)
                        <option value="{{ $province->id }}">{{ $province->province }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <select name="city_id" id="city_id" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0" required>Ciudad</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
           </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group text-left">
           {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block']) }}
       </div>

       {!! Form::close() !!}
   </div>
</div>
```

Ajax

```
$("#province").change(event=>{
  $.get("/dashboard/account/cities/"+event.target.value+"", function(response,province){
      $("#city_id").empty();
      for(i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
          $("#city_id").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].city+" </option>");
        }
    });
});
```

El javascript para mostrar el formulario según selección

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrar(id) {
if (id == "select") {
    $("#local").hide();
    $("#user").hide();
}
if (id == "local") {
    $("#local").show();
    $("#user").hide();
}
if (id == "user") {
    $("#local").hide();
    $("#user").show();
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, nos puedes mostrar como esta renderizando blade en el cliente (el html puro)?

Comment: Copio todo el html? tiene más de 400 líneas

Comment: No creo que sea necesario. Ya comprendí tu problema, como planteabas pense que tenias dos formularios con el mismo id, pero son dos campos con el mismo id. Mayor información te la daré en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, sí disculpa son dos campos

Comment: No deberías usar atributos `id` duplicados, los mismos están diseñados para ser únicos en un documento `html`. Si necesitas valores dinámicos en atributos `html`, te sugiero usar los atributos [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/data-*) que son [soportados](https://caniuse.com/#search=Data-*) en la mayoría de navegadores. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, lo tendré en cuenta para a próxima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a tu problema es el siguiente. Con la estructura de tu html puedes hacer uso de los `id` que tienes asignados como div padre de tus secciones `local` y `user`. Utilizando el `select` donde se asigna el valor para `status`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$('select[name=province_id]').on('change', function(){
    var province = $(this).val(); // obtienes el valor de la provincia
    var status = $('#status').val(); //obtenemos status puede ser select,local o user
    var input_city = $('#'+status).find('select[name=city_id]'); //buscamos dentro de #local o #user y obtenemos el select city_id
    $.get('/dashboard/account/cities/'+province, function(response){
        input_city.empty();
        for(i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
            input_city.append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].city+" </option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Otra manera de hacerlo sin depender del valor de status es el siguiente:

```
$('select[name=province_id]').on('change', function(){
    var province = $(this).val(); // obtienes el valor de la provincia
    var input_city = $(this).closest('form').find('select[name=city_id]'); //buscamos al padre mas cercano del tipo form y buscamos el select city_id
    $.get('/dashboard/account/cities/'+province, function(response){
        input_city.empty();
        for(i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
            input_city.append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'> "+response[i].city+" </option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias funconó muy bien.